# How to get datafrom my database sqllite in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to connect into my sqllite database but this throws me error table user not exist

In main I am calling this:
Connection.GetDataTable("select * from user");

What am I doing wrong please?

Now I just trying to make one universal connection object which I will use in my models to get data from database.

Connection.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SQLite;
//using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace Covid
{
    //////SQLite Edition
    class Connection
    {

        // Connection String for  SQlite Edition
        static string _ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\CovidDatabase;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True";

        // Use for ..exe.config file 
        //   static string _ConnectionString = Sqtlie_project_tutorial.Properties.Settings.Default.SqliteDBtestConnectionString1;

        static SQLiteConnection _Connection = null;
        public static SQLiteConnection Connections
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Connection == null)
                {
                    _Connection = new SQLiteConnection(_ConnectionString);
                    _Connection.Open();

                    return _Connection;
                }
                else if (_Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    _Connection.Open();

                    return _Connection;
                }
                else
                {
                    return _Connection;
                }
            }
        }

        public static DataSet GetDataSet(string sql)
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, Connections);
            SQLiteDataAdapter adp = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            Connections.Close();

            return ds;
        }

        public static DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sql);
            DataSet ds = GetDataSet(sql);

            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                return ds.Tables[0];
            return null;
        }

        public static int ExecuteSQL(string sql)
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, Connections);
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Structure]

here is database

[image: Database]

Comment: That error is clear that table user does not exist.  Are you sure that the copy of the db file where you are showing your database is getting copied to the folder where your application gets compiled to?

Comment: Yes this database on image is the same as you can see in my  ssolution. I just opened it via  db browser for sqllite

Comment: Is connection string good? I mean path? I am not sure.... doing this first time

Comment: `.\CovidDatabase` refers to the path from where your project is running... and that will be from `bin` folder.

Comment: Can I check if I am connected to database? I am not sure about it.... It dropp ingetDataSet adp-Fil(ds) line